# how to detect the key combination using keyboard hooks in C#

Tags: c#, .net, console, keylogger

I have created the code in which a console app runs in BG and detects the keys being pressed but the problem is that it does not detect The key combination Such as (Win+R = Run) , (Ctrl+B = Bold).
I am unable to understand how to detect the combinations of the key.

Comment: please refer to this article. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Comment: @Lakshay Bhalla Always provide your current code being used so if there's something missing, it can be pointed out; alongwith letting other people try out your code and improve